# how to use swagger in simple spring program

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, swagger

Following is the simple spring program how can i use swagger in this example ?
and is it possible to use swagger with following example ?

Following is the `Controller` class

```
@Controller
public class HelloController{

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView HelloWorld() {

        ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        m.addObject("WelcomeMesage","Hi User,welcome");

        return m;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/Hi")
    public ModelAndView HiWorld() {

        ModelAndView m=new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        m.addObject("WelcomeMesage","Hi User,welcome");

        return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: please give me all steps for using swagger in spring

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SpringFox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox) to document your API and then generate the OpenAPI/Swagger spec.

The [example](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos) is a good starting point.